# Angular 5 - Form Control with objects

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I'm currently working on an Angular application backed by Django.

One part of the application is that it needs to display a list of members. The members array looks somewhat like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'John Smith',
    id: 3,
    score_set: [...]
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    id: 7,
    score_set: [...]
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill Appleseed',
    id: 3,
    score_set: [...]
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob Lee',
    id: 3,
    score_set: [...]
  }
]
```

I got that working, but I also needed the user to be able to edit the names of those members. I tried using Reactive Forms to get this working:

First, I made a `FormGroup` consisting of just one `FormArray`. This `FormArray` basically contained all of the member objects:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  roster: this.fb.array(this.members.map((elem) => [elem, Validators.required]))
});
```

Next, I wrote out the template for the component:

```xml
<form>
  <div [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="roster">
      <div *ngFor="let control of form.controls.roster.controls">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" [formControl]="control" placeholder="Enter name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But instead of displaying the `name` property of each member it just tries to display the whole object, making `[Object object]`. Is there any way to configure each `FormControl` to use the `name` property as a value?

I want it so that only the name is displayed in the `<input>`, and when the user edits the `<input>` it updates the `name` property of the object, while retaining all the other properties.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're just missing the `.name`. Do it like this: `roster: this.fb.array(this.members.map(elem => [elem.name, Validators.required]))`

Comment: I could do that, but I want the `FormControl` to keep the object data as well, so I know which name goes with which object. Since I'm also going to add removing and adding members, if I only put the name in the `FormControl` I won't be able to know which object was edited.

Comment: I want the `FormControl` to internally keep the `{name: string, id: number, score_set: any[]}`, but I want it to display only `name` on the actual `<input>`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you want to keep the full object, you'll have to create `formGroups`, like this:

```
interface Member {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    roster: this.formBuilder.array(this.members.map(member => this.createMemberGroup(member))),
  });
}

createMemberGroup(member: Member): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    ...member,
    name: [member.name, Validators.required],
  });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form class="container pt-2" [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div formArrayName="roster">
    <div 
      [formGroupName]="index" 
      *ngFor="let control of formGroup.get('roster').controls; index as index">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input 
          class="form-control" 
          formControlName="name" 
          placeholder="Enter name" 
          [class.is-invalid]="control.invalid">
        <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="control.invalid">Required</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-zb38j7)

Comment: Doesn't making a `FormGroup` require me to add input fields for the other properties? I only want `name` to be editable

Comment: Or is it possible to put the other properties into the `FormGroup` but not make `<input>`s for them

Comment: Add properties to a `FormGroup` doesn't necessarily means that you want to edit them (which is your case). Check the demo.

Comment: Ok the one point this answer is missing, is that you can then do 'control.value.id' inside the loop and it will do what you think it will. Thank you