# formControlName showing [object,object]

Tags: angular

My FormControl has a JSON object and I'm binding it to the respective field and see the result as `[object,object]` in the view.

```
let fSource = {
 name: 'India',
 code: 'IN'
};

this.myForm.get('defaultLocation').setValue(fSource);
```

But I need to show the name (India) only in the input field. How do I bind it?

Comment: This answer might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604534/8351493

Comment: trying applying "  | json  " to see the data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
 this.myForm.get('defaultLocation').setValue(fSource.name);
```

Comment: Actually that object I'm getting from the server and I need to save that object otherwise, I need to save the remaining value in another variable.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what are you looking for..

Comment: In UI input field should show only the name 'India' but form-control has this value {
 name: 'India',
 code: 'IN'
};